# xslt - How to output data for a series of dates when some dates not in source xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt and after many attempts am not able to solve the below.

I have an xml data file which contains data I cannot change. For example the below simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sales>
    <sale>
        <year>2012</year>
        <amount>200</amount>
    </sale>
    <sale>
        <year>2012</year>
        <amount>180</amount>
    </sale>
    <sale>
        <year>2010</year>
        <amount>120</amount>
    </sale>
</sales>
```

I want to group the sale data on year and sum the amount so I get a total amount per year which I can do ok.

There is data for 2012 and 2010 but not for 2011 in the xml file.

I would like my output to have a figure of 0 for 2011 so I have output for all years 2010,2011 and 2012.

I am actually going to use the xls to produce a graph but in this simple example am using html as the output. I am using Altova XMLSpy to test the xls and see the resulting html document.

Here is the simple xls code I have written to group and display the data in HTML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="sales/sale" group-by="year">
      <xsl:sort select="year"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/amount)"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run this using Altova XMLSpy against the xml file I get the below in a browser window. A small table with 3 rows, a header with titles and then 2 rows of data, one for 2012, the other 2010. I can't use images yet as a new user to stackoverflow so here is the source html code that can be viewed in a browser.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2010</td>
                <td>120</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>380</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can I create a row for the Year 2011 with an amount of 0 using xls so that my output shows data for the range of years 2010,2011 and 2012?

Please note I cannot hard code Years in the xls, I have to derive the ones that are missing.

Ordinarily I would ensure the source xml file had all the data required but in this instance it is not possible.

Appreciate any help.

Kind Regards

Cel

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sale-by-year" match="sale" use="xs:integer(year)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="/"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="min(sales/sale/year/xs:integer(.)) to max(sales/sale/year/xs:integer(.))">
      <xsl:variable name="sales-of-year" select="key('sale-by-year', ., $doc)"/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!--  <xsl:value-of select="if ($sales-of-year) then sum($sales-of-year/amount) else 0"/> -->
          <xsl:value-of select="sum($sales-of-year/amount)"/>
        </td>
       </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 - the calculation of the sum could also be simplified to: ` <xsl:value-of select="sum($sales-of-year/amount)"/>`.

Comment: Thanks, Mads, I had forgotten of that behavior of the `sum` function but you are right, http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sum explains that the result of `sum(())` is the integer 0. I will edit my code.

Comment: Hi Martin and Mads, thank you both very much for looking and thinking about the question and for replying with a solution. Really appreciate it. I will copy the code and go through it in XMLSpy running it against the xml and checking with documentation on what the different sections/ elements exactly do. At first glance it looks like it 'loops' through dates from the min year date, 2010, to the maximum 2012 in the xml and sums the amount for each year in the xml file. As going from min to max it tests for an amount for year 2011 and as none the sum gives 0 (zero).

Comment: Sorry I changed this and did not realise there was a time limit on editing comments so could not save my edit. Meant to include at end that I can see it is using a key to derive the year date between the min and max and then check in the xml for an amount for that year. Thanks again Cel

Comment: Hi Mads, you have a small typo in your change to Martins xsl. "sum($sales-of-year/amout)", you have amount without an n. At least it shows I am actually running through the solutions as I spotted it when running it in XMLSpy. Cheers Cel

Comment: It was my typo, sorry about that. As for how the stylesheet works, yes, a for-each iterates over the sequence of year number from minimum to maximum and for each years computes the sum. The key is used for an efficient access.

Answer (score 0):

**I. Slightly shorter XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kSalesByYear" match="sale" use="year"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select=
         "min(/*/*/year/xs:integer(.)) to max(/*/*/year/xs:integer(.))">
         <tr>
           <td><xsl:sequence select="."/></td>
           <td><xsl:sequence select=
            "sum(key('kSalesByYear',string(.),$vDoc)/amount)"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kSalesByYear" match="sale" use="year"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMinMax">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/year">
   <xsl:sort/>
   <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('|',.)"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vMin" select="substring-before($vMinMax, '|')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vMax" select="substring-after($vMinMax, '|')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select=
         "(document('')//node()|document('')//@*|document('')//namespace::*)
           [not(position() > $vMax - $vMin +1)]
         ">
         <xsl:variable name="vYear" select="$vMin + position() -1"/>

         <xsl:for-each select="$vDoc">
             <tr>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="$vYear"/></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select=
                "sum(key('kSalesByYear',$vYear)/amount)"/></td>
             </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When any of the two transformationsabove are applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<sales>
    <sale>
        <year>2012</year>
        <amount>200</amount>
    </sale>
    <sale>
        <year>2012</year>
        <amount>180</amount>
    </sale>
    <sale>
        <year>2010</year>
        <amount>120</amount>
    </sale>
</sales>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2010</td>
            <td>120</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2011</td>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>380</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thank you very much for looking at my question and for providing solutions in both xls 1.0 and 2.0. I am going to work through them this morning in XMLSpy along with Mads and Martins so I understand what each section/ element is doing. Thanks again Cel

Comment: @cel, My XSLT 2.0 solution is almost identical to that of Martin Honnen -- don't know why it is slightly shorter. The XSLT 1.0 solution uses "the Piez" method to avoid recursion -- this relies on having sufficient number of nodes in the XSLT stylesheet -- probably may not work if there are large gaps -- such as 1, 10000, 20000. For this last case, a fully recursive XSLT solution code will be necessary.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - curious: why the `<xsl:for-each select="$vDoc">` instruction? I seem to be able to reproduce comparable results without that.

Comment: @ABach, This is necessary, in order to change the current document from that of the XSLT stylesheet to that of the XML document. The outer `xsl:for-each` sets the current document to `document('')` --that is the XSLT stylesheet. `key()` in XSLT 1.0 operates on the current document, and we want it to be the source XML document.